# how to get youtube videoId from url?

Tags: android, regex, kotlin, youtube

It doesn't matter, but the language I'm using is kotlin.

my get video Id code

```
fun getVideoIdFromYoutubeUrl(url: String?): String? {
        var videoId: String? = null
        val regex =
            "(?:https?:\\/\\/)?(?:www\\.)?youtu(?:\\.be\\/|be.com\\/\\S*(?:watch|shorts)(?:(?:(?=\\/[-a-zA-Z0-9_]{11,}(?!\\S))\\/)|(?:\\S*v=|v\\/)))([-a-zA-Z0-9_]{11,})"
           // "http(?:s)?:\\/\\/(?:m.)?(?:www\\.)?youtu(?:\\.be\\/|be\\.com\\/(?:watch\\?(?:feature=youtu.be\\&)?v=|v\\/|embed\\/|user\\/(?:[\\w#]+\\/)+))([^&#?\\n]+)"

        val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
        val matcher = pattern.matcher(url)
        if (matcher.find()) {
            videoId = matcher.group(1)
        }

        return videoId
    }
```

test youtube shots url

```
https://youtube.com/shorts/IC7M4up0FOI?feature=share
```

But when I do it with that regular expression, null is returned.

On the other hand, this url works just fine.

```
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/YK1po3GW9oY
```

what do i need to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this regex

```
/^.*(?:(?:youtu\.be\/|v\/|vi\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|shorts\/)|(?:(?:watch)?\?v(?:i)?=|\&v(?:i)?=))([^#\&\?]*).*/
```